# Disable lightweight visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Any way to disable light weight load in visual studio 2017?
When I load the solution it has "Solution 'MySolutionName' (loading... - lightweight)". I don't want this feature because my intellesens won't work correctly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Go to tools => Options => Projects and Solutions.

There you can see a checkbox named "Lightweight solution load for all solutions". Uncheck this.

It seems you also have to right click on your solution in Solution Explorer and click on Disable/Enable lightweight solutions load.

Now your solution should load correctly on a restart.

UPDATE: Since v15.5, "Lightweight Solution Load" has been removed.

> It provided lower than anticipated perf gains, forced devs to choose between faster solution load and a full set of VS features, and introduced complexity in developing extensions.

https://twitter.com/sarmatia7/status/938179364352679937

Answer (score 9):

Right click on the solution in solution explorer and select 'Disable lightweight solution load'

Answer (score 1):

There is a related setting that might be of interest as well:

We saw some lockups, especially during the start of Batch Builds, until we set this experimental feature to False:

**Tools** > **Options** : **Text Editor** > **C/C++** > **Experimental** : **Enable Faster Project Load**.